# How to output a screen from a submit handler? (D7)

Tags: 7, forms

Based upon a form's values In my submit handler I build the output screen and display it with a `drupal_set_message();`. I'm trying to figure out how to display the information on a page. I can't find any examples. I've created a theme, which is probably unnecessary, but again, I don't know how to display it.

Answer (score 2):

You want output form values after form on submit?

```
function mymodule_myform($form, $form_state) {
  $form['mytextfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'My Textfield',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );
  if (isset($form_state['values'])) {
    $form['page_output'] = array('#markup' => 'Submitted value: ' . $form_state['values']['mytextfield']);
  }
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I have the form values. See above response to writefleaCH. I should have referenced you in that response.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate, what you want to achieve. Output what exactly? What the user filled in the form? What does the form do? Email? Maybe https://drupal.org/project/webform is what you need?

Comment: I'm doing module development. I have a _form which contains the fields plus a submit. I have a _submit function which grabs the fields that wrtr entered, formats them into a report and I use drupa_set_message to output it. It works fine; but, I would like to format the output and render it to the screen. Not as a message. I can't figure out how to do this from the _submit function. A noobie question.